# Why ajax calls respond with permission denied

Tags: php, ajax, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have been using Amazon Web Services (AWS) to develop my web app. I use EC2, S3 and RDS. It's been a month since I started and suddenly ajax calls stopped working and respond with Permission Denied.

I have tried allowing all traffic from any source and changing the url in the ajax code to include the absolute path.

All my code is on a Free Tier EC2 instance (virtual machine). This is part of my ajax code, It's meant to validate a new username upon sign up:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'validateUsername.php',
    data: { usernameInput: usernameInputText },
    success : function(response) {
            //if sql query doesn't return a match
            //then username is valid and not taken
//                              alert("response: " + response);
            if(response == "username taken"){
                    usernameValid = false;
                    var popup = document.getElementById("usernameInvalidPopUp");
                    if(popup.innerHTML == "Please enter a username."){
                            popup.innerHTML = "Username taken";
                    }
                    else if(popup.innerHTML == ""){
                            popup.innerHTML = "Username taken";
                            popup.classList.toggle("show");
                    }
                    else{
                    }
            }
            if(response == "username available"){
                    var popup = document.getElementById("usernameInvalidPopUp");
                    if(popup.innerHTML == "Username taken" || popup.innerHTML == "Please enter a username."){
                            popup.classList.toggle("show");
                            popup.innerHTML = "";
                    }
                    usernameValid = true;

            }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("username Status: " + textStatus);
            alert("uError: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

and this is the server side script:

```
<?php
    //do not display error when there is no get or post values
    //ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    //error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

    $servername = "x";
    $username = "x";
    $password = "x";
    $dbname="x";
    // Create connection
    // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xnXHLHR3AE
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $username = $_GET["usernameInput"];

    //procedural style: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

    $usernameString = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username);

    // Prepare our SQL, preparing the SQL statement will prevent SQL injection.
    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?")) {
            // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), in our case the username is a string so we use "s"
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $usernameString);
            $stmt->execute();
            // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
            $stmt->store_result();

            if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
                    //$stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
                    //$stmt->fetch();
                    echo "username taken";
            }
            else{
                    echo  "username available";
            }
            $stmt->close();
    }
    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='".$usernameString."';";

    //$result = $conn->query($sql);

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You can call the PHP script directly using Postman. If that fails, your error is most likely server side and if it goes ok, that means you have a bug in JS.

If the error is on the server, make sure that your file permissions are set correctly. It could be that your web server doesn't have the rights to execute that PHP file.

Comment: The problem was that I had SELinux enabled. I disabled it by editing /etc/sysconfig/selinux.
```
nano /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had SELinux enabled. I disabled it by editing /etc/sysconfig/selinux.

```
nano /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

then setting SELINUX=disabled

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```